# Knockoutjs: Keep track of recursion depth?

Tags: javascript, recursion, knockout.js

I'm using a recursive template which can shortly be summarized as follows:

```
<script id="template-name" type="text/html">
    <div data-bind="foreach: $data">
        <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
        <div data-bind="template: { name: 'template-name', data: children }"></div>
    </div>
</script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'template-name', data: $data }"></div>
```

What I would like to do, however, is to keep track of the current recursion depth somehow. How would I approach this using Knockout?
I've tried a number of approaches, but I'm not familiar enough with Knockout to figure out where I'm making a mistake.

```
<script id="template-name" type="text/html">
    <div data-bind="foreach: $data[0]">
        <span data-bind="text: $data[1].toString()"></span>:<span data-bind="text: title"></span>
        <div data-bind="template: { name: 'template-name', data: ko.observableArray([children, ++$data[1]]) }"></div>
    </div>
</script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'template-name', data: ko.observableArray([$data, 0]) }"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was easy to figure out once I found a way to debug the current context for Knockout. You can use either [the Knockout Context Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en) or just throw raw json to your document using

```
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

In the end, the syntax I went with was

```
<script id="template-name" type="text/html">
    <div data-bind="foreach: $data.children">
        <span data-bind="text: $parent.depth"></span>:<span data-bind="text: title"></span>
        <div data-bind="template: { name: 'template-name', data: { children: children, depth: ($parent.depth + 1) } }"></div>
    </div>
</script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'template-name', data: { children: $data, depth: 0 } }"></div>
```

Comment: interesting one . I never use templates but good to know something on this .